# Being prompted to use Redeem code with Testflight Public Sharing link

Tags: testflight, testflight-public-link

I have been sharing a public link for my testflight app and whilst some users are able to download without any problems, others are prompted by testflight to add their redeem code (Which I cannot find anywhere) Anyone know why?

Here's the link
https://testflight.apple.com/join/EyUDjsLx

Thanks 
Andrew

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed this issue as well.
What worked for me was : having the user click the link again, AFTER installing testflight

Comment: This should be the accepted answer to this problem.

Comment: Same problem but this workaround doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Close TF app and reopen it. The app should wait there for you to install.